# How to extend an abstract xsd element from another NS

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm working on a SCAP implementation and I need to add a vendor asset type to ARF reports.
The ARF schema is located here https://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-reporting-format/1.1/asset-reporting-format_1.1.0.xsd (used with arf prefix)
The asset identification xsd is here https://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-identification/1.1/asset-identification_1.1.0.xsd (used with ai prefix)

So what I fail to achieve is adding some vendor ai:asset-type implementation in an ARF report that still validates ARF schema. I wrote a vendor namespace that only define an element wich extends ai:asset-type and has a substitutionGroup="ai:asset" attribute but when validating a report that uses this vendor element against ARF schema, the validation tool returns that arf:asset only alllow children defined in the asset identification NS. Though, the AI schema is supposed to allow extensions. Any Idea ?

Edit :

Here's how I tried to add the custom vendor element my-asset :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ai="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-identification/1.1"
           xmlns:my-ns="http://mydomain/schema/scap/asset-identification/1.0"
           targetNamespace="http://mydomain/schema/scap/asset-identification/1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.1.1" xmlns:cpe-name="http://cpe.mitre.org/naming/2.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-identification/1.1" schemaLocation="https://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-identification/1.1/asset-identification_1.1.0.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="my-asset" type="my-ns:my-asset-type" substitutionGroup="ai:asset" />
    <xs:complexType name="my-asset-type">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="ai:asset-type">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="ai:cpe" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Edit 2:

The instance that I'm trying to validate against ARF schema :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arf:asset-report-collection xmlns:ai="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-identification/1.1"
  xmlns:arf="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-reporting-format/1.1"
  xmlns:core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/reporting-core/1.1"
  xmlns:my-ns="http://mydomain/schema/scap/asset-identification/1.0"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://mydomain/schema/scap/asset-identification/1.0
    http://mydomain/schema/scap/asset-identification/1.0/asset-identification_1.0.a.xsd
    http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-reporting-format/1.1
    https://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-reporting-format/1.1/asset-reporting-format_1.1.0.xsd
  ">
  <core:relationships xmlns:arfvocab="http://scap.nist.gov/specifications/arf/vocabulary/relationships/1.0#"
      xmlns:aivocab="https://scap.nist.gov/specifications/ai/vocabulary/relationships/1.0/#"
      xmlns:myvocab="https://mydomain/riskmanager/relationships/#">
    <core:relationship type="myvocab:supports" subject="asset_id_generated_by_app_2">
      <core:ref>asset_id_generated_by_app_3</core:ref>
    </core:relationship>
    <core:relationship type="aivocab:installedOnDevice" subject="asset_2">
      <core:ref>asset_1</core:ref>
    </core:relationship>
  </core:relationships>
  <arf:assets>
    <arf:asset id="asset_id_generated_by_app_1">
      <my-ns:my-asset id="uniq_vendor_id_1">
        <ai:cpe>cpe:/a:linux:debian:7.0</ai:cpe>
        <ai:cpe>cpe:/a:apache:http_server:2.2</ai:cpe>
      </my-ns:my-asset>
    </arf:asset>
    <arf:asset id="asset_id_generated_by_app_2">
      <my-ns:my-asset id="uniq_vendor_id_2">
        <ai:cpe>cpe:/a:linux:debian:7.0</ai:cpe>
      </my-ns:my-asset>
    </arf:asset>
    <arf:asset id="asset_id_generated_by_app_3">
      <my-ns:my-asset id="uniq_vendor_id_3">
        <ai:cpe>cpe:/a:apache:http_server:2.2</ai:cpe>
      </my-ns:m-asset>
    </arf:asset>
    <arf:asset id="asset_1">
      <ai:computing-device>
        <ai:connections>
          <ai:connection>
            <ai:ip-address>
              <ai:ip-v4>192.168.2.10</ai:ip-v4>
            </ai:ip-address>
          </ai:connection>
        </ai:connections>
        <ai:fqdn>comp1234.tempuri.org</ai:fqdn>
      </ai:computing-device>
    </arf:asset>
    <arf:asset id="asset_2">
      <ai:software>
        <ai:cpe>cpe:/a:apache:http_server:2.2</ai:cpe>
      </ai:software>
    </arf:asset>
  </arf:assets>
  <arf:reports>
    <arf:report id="report_1">
      <arf:content>
        <report xmlns="http://mydomain/riskmanager/report" />
      </arf:content>
    </arf:report>
  </arf:reports>
</arf:asset-report-collection>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could supply the vendor namespace schema that you wrote, maybe there is something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be something wrong with the instance. The schema looks fine. The following validates successfully against the my-ns schema on my side. Maybe this helps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arf:asset-report-collection
    xmlns:arf="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-reporting-format/1.1"
    xmlns:my-ns="http://mydomain/schema/scap/asset-identification/1.0"
    xmlns:ai="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-identification/1.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://mydomain/schema/scap/asset-identification/1.0 test.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-reporting-format/1.1 asset-reporting-format_1.1.0.xsd.xml">
    <arf:assets>
        <arf:asset id="a">
            <my-ns:my-asset>
                <ai:cpe>cpe:/</ai:cpe>
            </my-ns:my-asset>
        </arf:asset>
    </arf:assets>
    <arf:reports>
        <arf:report id="foo">
            <arf:content><my-ns:foo/></arf:content>
        </arf:report>
    </arf:reports>
</arf:asset-report-collection>
```

Comment: Does your instance validate against https://scap.nist.gov/schema/asset-reporting-format/1.1/asset-reporting-format_1.1.0.xsd , because it's actually my main trouble. The custom element being from a type that extends ai:asset-type and substituable with ai:asset should(?) be valid as content from arf:asset elements but it's not. My validation tool keep telling me that arf:asset elements only allow asset, circuit, computing-device, data, database, network, organization, person, service or software as child

Comment: The instance validates against the set of all schemas, including yours, ai and arf (look at the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute, which takes arf and yours as entry points). It is important that your schema is in scope as well, otherwise the engine cannot possibly know that there is this substitution group. Also, note that validation engines may have different ways to bind schemas. I used oXygen.

Comment: The instance you provided in the question validates fine on my side, but I needed to change the name of the element from `my-asset` to `supporting-asset` in the schema, and to change the URL of your schema to my local version. I hope this helps. The issue you are having is probably specific to setting up the schemas properly on the validation software you are using. From an XML Schema perspective, apart from the element name typo, it all looks fine to me.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I corrected it. As of validation, it's strange that both the tools I used (libxml2 and xerces) reports me that arf:asset only alllow ai:asset and it's derived elements declared in ai schema or arf:remote-source. Anyway, thanks for your highlights, I'll now have to investigate on tools.

Comment: It is probably something specific to these tools. I think it's likely that they support this one way or the other (oXygen does use Xerces I think), but the XML Schema specification gives freedom to libraries as of how this is done in practice. For example, a tool may even choose to ignore the `xsi:schemaLocation` hint and use an alternate way (like force a unique schema over a large set of files).

Comment: Well this is it, in fact the tool based on Xerces I used only needs the instance schema. Calling it with schema verification somehow only validated the instance against the given schema. As of libxml based tools, it needs a global schema that imports each of the schemas to validate against.